# Updating constraint layout to relative cause error

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to use relative layout instead of constraint layout but when I change XML file header to relative layout, all the tools stick to the top.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

When I change this to relative layout, all the buttons and textview go to the left corner.

```
<RelativeLayout
</RelativeLayout>
```

As I am new to android studio, I was unable to understand this .

Comment: open a book about this topic

Comment: Sure i will  and thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Could you show us what you've done or something

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the constraints for example:

`app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/text"`.

These are the constraints for constraint layout.

For relative layout, you will have to use 
`android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"` for left to right alignment.

For more information read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative) link.